# Can service class in Java have state or member fields inside it?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a several calculator classes that that computes something for user.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Input{

    private Info info;
    private ResultAlpha resultAlpha;
    private ResultBeta resultBeta;
    private ResultGamma resultGamma;
    private ResultPsi resultPsi;
    private ResultLambda resultLambda;
    private ResultAph resultAph;

}
```

```
public class CalculationService(){
    

    private Info info;
    private ResultAlpha resultAlpha;
    private ResultBeta resultBeta;
    private ResultGamma resultGamma;
    private ResultPsi resultPsi;
    private ResultLambda resultLambda;
    private ResultAph resultAph;


    CalculationService(Input input){
        info = input.getInfo;
        resultAlpha = input.getResultAlpha();
        resultBeta =input.getResultBeta();
        resultGamma=input.getResultGamma();
        resultAph = input.getResultAph();
        resultLambda =input.getResultLambda();
        resultPsi = input.getResultPsi();
    }

    public void calculate(){

        calculate1();
        calculate2();
        calculate3();
        calculate4();
        calculate5();
        calculate6();

    }

    private void calculate1(){

    }

    private void calculate2(){

    }

    private void calculate3(){

    }

    private void calculate4(){

    }

    private void calculate5(){

    }

    private void calculate6(){

    }

}
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class DemoService {


    public void executeCalculation(Input input){

        CalculatorService calculatorService = new CalculatorService(input);

        calculatorService.calculate();

        //save Input in db
        
    }

}
```

I did not want to pass all the variables into calculate method so I have saved a reference of all the fields inside Input class in the calculator class. This helps me to avoid sending all the arguments inside every calculate function. But I will have to make a new object for CalculationService every time I call it for a new user, otherwise it will not be thread safe.

One alternative I have is the following approach -

```
public final class CalculationService(){


    private CalculationService(){
    
    }

    public static void calculate(Input input){
   

        Info info = input.getInfo();
        ResultAlpha resultAlpha = input.getResultAlpha();
        ResultBeta resultBeta =input.getResultBeta();
        ResultGamma resultGamma=input.getResultGamma();
        ResultAph resultAph = input.getResultAph();
        ResultLambda resultLambda =input.getResultLambda();
        ResultPsi resultPsi = input.getResultPsi();

        calculate1(info, resultAlpha, resultBeta, resultGamma, resultAph, resultLambda, resultPsi);
        calculate2(info, resultAlpha, resultBeta, resultGamma, resultAph, resultLambda, resultPsi);
        calculate3(info, resultAlpha, resultBeta, resultGamma, resultAph, resultLambda, resultPsi);
        calculate4(info, resultAlpha, resultBeta, resultGamma, resultAph, resultLambda, resultPsi);
        calculate5(info, resultAlpha, resultBeta, resultGamma, resultAph, resultLambda, resultPsi);
        calculate6(info, resultAlpha, resultBeta, resultGamma, resultAph, resultLambda, resultPsi);

    }

    private static void calculate1(Info, ResultAlpha, ResultBeta, ResultGamma, ResultAph, ResultLambda, ResultPsi){

    }

    private static void calculate2(Info, ResultAlpha, ResultBeta, ResultGamma, ResultAph, ResultLambda, ResultPsi){

    }

    private static void calculate3(Info, ResultAlpha, ResultBeta, ResultGamma, ResultAph, ResultLambda, ResultPsi){

    }

    private static void calculate4(Info, ResultAlpha, ResultBeta, ResultGamma, ResultAph, ResultLambda, ResultPsi){

    }

    private static void calculate5(Info, ResultAlpha, ResultBeta, ResultGamma, ResultAph, ResultLambda, ResultPsi){

    }

    private static void calculate6(Info, ResultAlpha, ResultBeta, ResultGamma, ResultAph, ResultLambda, ResultPsi){

    }

}
```

This would not require to create an instance of object of CalculationService class.

My main problem is that since Input class is a deeply nested object, I want to avoid lot of getter functions when trying to use data from Input class. And that is the main reason why I tried to break the Input objects into its member fields. Otherwise, my calculation function will have long getter calls like

```
input.getResultAlpha().getObj2().getObj3().getObj4().setData(1234);
```

So is it okay to save state in Service classes as I did in the first approach?

Comment: Its not a good practice to call this kind of class "Helper".
generally a helper holds only static methods ( for example [StringUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html) ).
You have more likely a conception problem

Comment: I'd call it a "service", but whatever. Of course it's okay--whatever makes the most sense based on requirements etc. I don't see much point in destructuring the input object, unless it really helps keep things cleaner.

Comment: @ggr So let's say it's not a helper class. Would it be okay to go with first approach? We'll have to initialise the class in the first case

Comment: As almost everyone use Spring now, I will go with the second option : pass the all parameters to each methods. It's a more actual style of programming

Comment: @ggr That would be a *utility class*, hence the name String**Utils**. The term *helper class* is a superset that also includes classes with instance fields.

Comment: @DaveNewton "Service" has a different connotation, from the "service" layer of a multi-layered architecture, so saying to call such a class a "service" class instead of a "helper" class, is actually confusing the terminology.

Comment: @Andreas, I do agreee but who's doing full OOP with Java in 2020 ? I mean professionally ?

Comment: @ggr 1) [Multi-layered architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) has nothing to do with OOP ([Object-Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)). They are entirely independent concepts. --- 2) Professionally? Anyone who works are *large* projects. Spring is very multi-layer friendly, so don't know why you think that using Spring would prevent it or make it difficult. Layer 1: @Controller beans. Layer 2: `@Service` beans. Layer 3: `@Repository` beans.

Comment: @Andreas I think we do agree, but there are just some incomprehension. We are loosing the issue of sight.
As DaveNewton said : readability first.

Comment: @Andreas *shrug* We'll agree to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helper_class) says it:

> In object-oriented programming, a **helper class** is used to assist in providing some functionality, which isn't the main goal of the application or class in which it is used. An instance of a helper class is called a **helper object** (for example, in the delegation pattern).

> A **utility class** is a special case of a helper class in which the methods are all static. In general, helper classes do not have to have all static methods, but may have instance variables. Multiple instances of the helper class may exist as well.

As you can see, helper classes are not just classes of static methods, they can also be regular POJO classes with instance fields and instance methods.

So instead of using it statically, use an instance:

```java
// Static helper
CalculationHelper.calculate(input);

// Instance helper
CalculationHelper helper = new CalculationHelper(input);
helper.calculate();
```

Comment: My main concern is that this object gets created for every user request, is it okay to to create a instance helper or try to change my class structure to static helper.

Would creating new object for every request be a code smell or frowned upon? since most of the service classes I have seen in Spring have singleton bean

Comment: @Abhinav There's nothing wrong with creating a new object for every request. You haven't shown us the code of `Info` or the `Result*` classes, but assuming these are simply POJOs the JVM is extremely efficient at creating and garbage collecting small objects.

Comment: @Abhinav Why would creating an instance for every request be code smell? If you need to track extra information about a request, to e.g. pass along between method calls and/or "layers", then you *need* an instance to store that information, especially if methods can add more data about the request.

Comment: @DavidConrad Actually these info and result classes are huge as they are DTO classes. But would the size of the info and result classes really matter to JVM as I'm only storing reference here?

Comment: @Abhinav Huge and DTO sounds strange to me, DTOs are generally not huge in my experience, but you haven't shown us those. But the bigger issue is that you are just storing references. So this is mutable data? And the whole point of allocating an object for each request is to avoid concurrency issues? Sharing mutable state defeats that purpose. You might as well just let the calculate methods access the data through the fields of their class.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, this is a mutable data since I've wanted to change the input class as it passes through different calculator classes. I had allocated objects to avoid concurrency issue. Can you please elaborate how sharing mutable state defeats the purpose since these calculator classes will pertain to a single request. This input class will not be accessed concurrently by another request. So everything works on a single request till the end flow. Can you please point me to some resource if you think I'm not making sense?

Comment: @Abhinav Well, I guess I'm just not understanding, then. The calculator class has all these Info, ResultAlpha, etc. fields and then the Input class has all these Info, ResultAlpha etc. fields. If the calculator classes pertain to a single request, why not just use those? If the mutable data can be changed by more than one request, then you're going to have a bad time. But I've only seen what you posted.

Comment: @DavidConrad I have added the Spring service class so hope now it makes sense that these input and calculator classes will be thread safe. My doubt is that should I take approach 1 in which I have tried to store member fields of input class in calculator class or the approach 2 where I am not storing member fields of input class in calculator class. My reason to take approach 1 was that it helps me to destructure the input class and easily access them in calculate functions but it worries me that it's something like making variables global which is obviously a code-smell.

Comment: @DavidConrad It's just that approach 1 helps me to avoid an extra getter like
input.getResultAlpha().getObj1().getObj2().